# Data mining approach for detecting higher level clones in softwares

Tags: clone, data-mining

Im doing a project based on the topic above. Please let me know if there are any applications based on this topic already done in the past. If not Please let me know where I would make a starting as I hav a very little undersanding of the topic.

The abstract can be read [here](http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~stan/PAPERS/CloneMiner%20TSE.pdf).

Thankyou.

Comment: And what is wrong with the paper you refer to?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a tool suite called [ConQAT](http://conqat.in.tum.de/index.php/CloneDetective) might be usefull to you. I'm not sure if the clone detection is as high level as you might need it. But it could be a good starting point because of its open source nature.